# Boundedness of singular integral operators on $L^{p}$ spaces

Tags: fourier-analysis, operator-theory, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

Let $\Omega \in L^{1}(S^{d-1})$ have mean zero. Prove that, if the operator 
$T_{\Omega}: L^{p} \rightarrow L^{q}$ given by $T_{\Omega}f(x) $:= p.v. $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \frac{\Omega \left(\frac{y}{|y|} \right)}{|y|^{d}}f(x-y) dy$, $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ is bounded, then $p = q$.

The hint says to use dilations. I set $\tau_{y}(f(x)) = f(x-y)$ and then note that $T_{\Omega}$ is translation invariant. I can show that $\lim_{y \to \infty}||f+ \tau_{y}||_{p} = 2^{p^{-1}}||f||_{p}$. Denoting the norm of $T_{\Omega}$ by $||T_{\Omega}||_{p,q}$. Since $T_{\Omega}$ commutes with translations, we have $||T_{\Omega}f + \tau_{y}T_{\Omega}f||_{q} \leq ||T_{\Omega}||_{p, q}||f + \tau_{y}f||_{p}$ and on taking the limit as $y \to \infty$, we get $||T_{\Omega}f||_{q} \leq 2^{p^{-1} - q^{-1}}||T||_{p,q}||f||_{p} \implies p \leq q$. This does not quite give the equality though.

Comment: Since the hint says use dilations, why not try using dilations? Dilations are not translations. For $\lambda>0$ let $\delta_\lambda f(x)=f(\lambda x)$; work out how $T$ plays with $\delta_\lambda$.

Comment: I still cannot see how to make this work. Your hint here is basically saying 'use the hint.' A suggestion on how to use the hint would have been helpful .

Comment: You can apply for a refund if you want... Do some calculations; figure out what powers of $\lambda$ make the following true: (i) $T(\delta_\lambda f)=\lambda^?\delta_\lambda(Tf)$. (ii) $||\delta_\lambda f||_p=\lambda^?||f||_p$. (iii) Similarly for $||.||_q$. Now if $||Tf||_q\le c||f||_p$ it follows that $||T\delta_\lambda f||_q\le c||\delta_\lambda f||_p$. This leads to $\lambda^?\le\lambda^{??}$. Since that holds for all $\lambda>0$ you must have $?=??$.

Comment: This is very useful. I upvoted this:-)